# Rails 5.0 - How to check if record is associated on another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

Before destroying a record, I'd like to check if there are any uses of it on other tables, *even if the record itself has no knowledge of said uses*.

For example, lets say I have a table of `cost_centers`, and I have a table of `areas`.

An `area` has a default `cost_center`. `cost_centers` have no connection with `areas`.

Which kind of `validation` can I use in order to prevent the user from destroying a `cost_center`, in order to keep an `area` consistent?

In other words, how can I search through the database to find out wether that record is a foreign key of some other record on any other tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you designed your database, you've probably set all the references up.
In your migrations, it would look like this: `t.references :cost_center`.

If so, your Cost Center Model could have a `has_one` relationship to each table holding the reference which, in your example, would be `has_one :area`.

Then, to check if it is actually used, you could have a `before_destroy` callback to a method that checks if any `has_one` definition is not null:

```
class CostCenter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :area
  before_destroy :check_usage

  def check_usage
    !self.area.nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: but then I'd need to let the Cost Center know of every model that consumes it, right? Is it not possible to have a "pool" of Cost Centers which are consumed by other tables, while the Cost Center is oblivious of said other tables?

Comment: Well, there's two fronts here: Database and Rails. In the database, I **strongly** advise in having all the `references` set up for **integrity**. In Rails, however, you don't have to force a `has_one` directive.
For your idea to work, however, you need to know who uses your model because so many other models could be using it. Not only that, since your `CostCenter` model is the central piece, it really should handle this logic otherwise you'll have a LOT of repeated code even if you do use `concern`s.